# Test Mail error: no implicit conversion of nil into Hash [SPREE 3.3]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm triying to send mails with Spree but i keep getting this error in production. I'm using Heroku to deploy de App.

When I click "Send Test Mail" I get this error `Test Mail error: no implicit conversion of nil into Hash`.

gemfile:

```
#Spree Gems
gem 'spree', '~> 3.3.0'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.3'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.3'
gem 'spree_mail_settings', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_mail_settings'+
```

My Spree configuration:
[image]

I do not know what else to do to make this thing work. Also don't know when a how Spree send mails.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue

Answer (score 1):

It looks like spree_mail_settings was removed from Spree because of it having lots of issues and gotchas. I'm removing it from my project and am going to setup the standard Rails ActionMailer.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#example-action-mailer-configuration